# How to maintain existing layer names from input rasters when applying `terra::merge()` function?

Tags: terra

Layer names are carried over from input rasters when I use `terra::mosaic()`, but not when I use `terra::merge()`.

`terra::merge()` currently results in a numbered list prefixed by "lyr". E.g., "lyr1"  "lyr2"  "lyr3"

Is there an option in `terra::merge()` that will apply the input layer names?

edit: code if helpful...

```
stdMetricTiles <- list.files("D:/Projects2022/Test", "tif$", full.names = TRUE) # the $ excludes aux files

stdMetricSpatRasterCollection <- sprc(lapply(stdMetricTiles, rast))

stdMetricMosaic <- terra::mosaic(stdMetricSpatRasterCollection)
names(stdMetricMosaic)

stdMetricMerge <- terra::merge(stdMetricSpatRasterCollection)
names(stdMetricMerge)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume all your files in `stdMetricTiles` have the same layer names. So I will use the name of the layers from the first raster to transfer it to the resulting merge file.

```
# Retrieve the layer names from the first raster
names <- names(terra::rast(stdMetricTiles[[1]])

# Assign the layer names to the stdMetricMerge object
names(stdMetricMerge) <- names
```

Comment: thanks, this is a good work around. I had to change one line to work with the tif inputs: names <- names(terra::rast(stdMetricTiles[1]))   Do we need two square brackets? I am hoping that this could be an inline option for merge or default like mosaic, so I will leave this open a bit.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. I thought the `stdMetricTiles` list contained the SpatRaster objects instead of the paths to the files. I corrected my answer.

Comment: It is not necessary to use double brackets, but I recommend it when working with list-like objects, like in this case `stdMetricTiles`. Here you can find more information about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-bracket-and-double-bracket-for-accessing-the-el